# Which process is needed to complete male reproductive development?

Tags: homework, reproduction, embryology

In order to properly complete male reproductive development:

```
A. primordial germ cells must begin Meiosis I in utero.
B. Sertoli cells must produce testosterone.
C. Dihydrotestosterone must masculinize Wolffian duct derivatives
D. the paramesonephric ducts must degenerate
E. the metanephros must form the genital epithelium
```

My attempt:  I think the answer is C because testosterone turns into DHT which then masculinzing the wolffian duct.  Other people I am studying with claim the answer is D (which is true) except that I dont think the loss of the paramesonephric duct is needed to complete male repro development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding option C**:

Although it is correct that testosterone is converted into DHT, it is the former, not the latter, which is responsible for differentiation of the mesonephric (a.k.a. Wolffian) ducts:

> Between 8 and 12 weeks, the initial secretion of testosterone stimulates mesonephric ducts to transform into a system of organs—the epididymis, vas deferens, and seminal vesicle—that connect the testes with the urethra.*

DHT (dihydrotestosterone) is produced in the Leydig cells by the 5α-Reductase enzyme. It is required for induction of the external male genitalia (urethra, penis, and scrotum) and prostate from the embryonic ureteral groove, and for testicular descent into scrotum.

**Regarding option D:**

Sertoli cells secrete Anti Müllerian Hormone (AMH), which causes degeneration of the müllerian (a.k.a. paramesonephric) ducts between weeks 8 and 10.  It is normal to speak about *degeneration* of the müllerian ducts as a defining aspect of male embryology, and thus I believe answer **D** is correct. Your point is taken, however:

> Nevertheless, small müllerian duct remnants can be detected in the adult male, including a small cap of tissue associated with the testis, called the appendix testis, and an expansion of the prostatic urethra, called the prostatic utricle.*

---

<sup>*Larsen's Human Embryology , Fourth Edition. *Chapter 15: Development of the Urogenital System*. pp 479-541. 
Copyright © 2009 by Churchill Livingstone, an imprint of Elsevier Inc.</sup>